# How to keep underlying file when deleting a Filefield value

Tags: 7, files, media

I have a Content Type with a FileField (Image, in particular). When one of these values is deleted, then Drupal deletes the underlying file as well (as long as no other nodes reference the same file).

I don't want the underlying files to be deleted, I want them to remain in the filesystem. Are there any hooks or other techniques I can use to make sure it remains after its FileField value is deleted?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to acomplish?  Why do you need to keep the old file if you're going to allow it to be replaced anyway?  It feels like there may be a better solution than hacking core, or unlinking Filefields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an ugly hack, but this is the simplest way I found to prevent a file from being deleted. It works by hooking `file_delete` and then removing the `uri` property from the `$file` variable. Without the uri, Drupal is unable to delete the file.

```
// Think twice before using this ugly hack.
// It probably breaks something and kills kittens.
function mymodule_file_delete($file) {
  $path = drupal_realpath($file->uri);
  if (!is_dir($path) && is_file($path)) {
    if (preg_match('/insert_regex_here/', $path)) {
      $file->uri = NULL;
    }
  }
}
```

The other alternatives I considered were:

- **Hacking core**
  Although hacking core is taboo, it would be a cleaner solution than the hook I use above.
- **Using [file_usage_add()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_usage_list/7) on each file I want to retain**
  Doesn't fit my use case very well - tens of thousands of files created and deleted independently of Drupal. Synchronizing all those files with `file_usage_add` would be daunting.
- **Use [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module to reference the file paths**
  Media seems like overkill and it isn't stable yet. Plus I'm not sure if it would do what I need.

Comment: I ended up hacking core (edited `drupal_unlink()`) because it was the simplest solution and didn't have the potential side-effects that could come from abusing `hook_file_delete`. I'm still open to better suggestions.

Comment: For those who really think that they want to hack core: Open `includes/file.inc` and look for the function `drupal_unlink`. Add `return FALSE;` as the first line and NO files will be deleted. Better yet, add a conditional statement that checks the `$uri` to ensure that it is a file that you don't want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101754/drupal-filefield-remove-file-from-node-but-leave-on-server

Comment: That's a nice start. I'll have to see if Drupal 7 works in a similar way.