# How can I keep the files uploaded by filefield module even though users delete them on node edit form?

Tags: 6, entities, media, files

On my site users can upload photos by using CCK image field.  However I would like to keep the  images uploaded by users on the server even though users delete them on node edit form.

I'm not sure if this is possible or not..  Or backing up the images frequently is the only way?

Comment: possible duplicate of this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2090/how-to-keep-underlying-file-when-deleting-a-filefield-value

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually on drupal 6. I tried to hack the core as it's described but I couldn't find function drupal_unlink in includes/file.inc. Sorry I'm not a coder and I can't figure out how to convert the way from Drupal7 to Drupal6.  Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I used a module called [Filefield Sources](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) together with [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce). And on the file field's configuration page, I enabled the "IMCE Browser" option for additional sources.

I did a few tests and any files attached to a node using the "IMCE Browser" method doesn't get deleted when the file is removed from a node on node edit screen. But files added through the normal "Upload" method do get deleted, so I think you should upload files using the IMCE Browser too as it has a file uploader as well.

I'm not sure how to remove or hide the actual default "Upload" method on the file field though.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This method seems to work if the default "Upload" can be removed. I'll keep on searching the way to do that.