# Transfer Value of Field to Another Field under Content Type Manage Fields

Tags: 7

I have created several content types and unfortunately, I made a mistake on some of the fields. The fields are field_image and field_screenshot.

Under manage fields, I use field_image and sometimes field_screenshot. Now I want to use one field only for featured image on my node content. So, how can I transfer the value of field_image to field_screenshot? Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure about images, but for text you can use VBO: http://smartwolverine.net/article/drupal-7-copying-fields-inside-nodes-using-vbo. Maybe try this first?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not easily possible through the Drupal interface. You will need to execute a custom SQL query to move your data from one field to another.

The following two queries will copy all field data from field_image to field_screenshot **for each entity where field_screenshot is empty**.

```
INSERT INTO field_data_field_screenshot
SELECT a.* 
FROM field_data_field_image a
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_screenshot b ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id
AND a.entity_type = b.entity_type
WHERE b.entity_id IS NULL
```

and

```
INSERT INTO field_revision_field_screenshot
SELECT a.* 
FROM field_revision_field_image a
LEFT JOIN field_revision_field_screenshot b ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id
AND a.entity_type = b.entity_type
WHERE b.entity_id IS NULL
```

After running this you can then delete the first field.

If field_screenshot alreadly has data that you want to overwrite you will need to  delete it first using these queries. **Make sure this is what you want to do first because this WILL delete your data**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE field_data_field_screenshot
TRUNCATE TABLE field_revision_field_screenshot
```

Comment: Hi, When I deleted the field_image and replaced it with field_screenshot, all of the images are gone. The image url has this value `<img src="http://www.sourcecodester.com/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public?itok=IYh6TS4U" alt>`. I notice that the value of the images are deleted under `file_managed` table. Any help please. I don't know what to do now. I still have the backup copy of the images.

Comment: Never mind. I already fixed the problem. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Thomas4019, I want to transfer another field from `field_code` to `field_code_file`. Can I use the same query above and just change the field name say from `field_data_field_image` to `field_data_field_code` and `field_data_field_screenshot` to `field_data_field_code_file`?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Just make sure to backup your database first just in case anything goes wrong.

Comment: The only problem I am facing now is when I delete the old field. When it's deleted, the file is also deleted. So how can I delete the old field but retain the file?

Comment: You could TRUNCATE the table with SQL of the old field and then remove the field. If you do that Drupal won't delete any files.

Comment: @jaypabs May be this is helpfull then http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2090/how-to-keep-underlying-file-when-deleting-a-filefield-value

Comment: How to use this query sing db_insert();

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in a module with COMBO of [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7) and [db_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_insert/7)

```
$result = db_query('SELECT a.* 
  FROM {field_data_field_image} a
  LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_screenshot} b ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id
  AND a.entity_type = b.entity_type
  WHERE b.entity_id IS NULL'
);

$records = $result->fetchAll();
foreach ($records as $record) {
  db_insert('field_data_field_screenshot') // Table name no longer needs {}
        ->fields(array(
          'entity_type' => $record->entity_type,
          'bundle' => $record->bundle,
          'deleted' => $record->deleted,
          'entity_id' => $record->entity_id,
          . // All Columns
          .
          .
          .
        ->execute();
}
```

And repeat the revision field as well.