# How to Delete A Field and Retain Its Value?

Tags: 7

I created a new field called `field_code_file` and I transferred all the value from `field_code`. Reference [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97113/transfer-value-of-field-to-another-field-under-content-type-manage-fields/97115).

Now if I delete the old field called `field_code`, the value in `field_code_file` is also deleted. So how can I delete `field_code` by retaining the value in `field_code_file`?

BTW, not only the value that is being deleted but also the files. What I'm doing is simply restore the files from the backup. The only problem I have is to retain the value in the table, whatever table it is.

Anyone can help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this can help you, but one solution that I can suggest is to update your nodes (instead of directly querying the database): transfer one field values to the second one and save it then delete the first one. You can use [entity_metadata_wrapper](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_metadata_wrapper/7) or just functions that are provided by node module.
You can try something like this... Example:

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => 'MY_CONTENT_TYPE'));
foreach($nodes as $node) {
  $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  $field_code = $node_wrapper->field_code->value();
  $node_wrapper->field_code_file->set($field_code);
  $node_wrapper->save();
}
```