# How to re-upload an image but not removing it

Tags: media

I have an image field which has 1 value limited. I need to change the uploading photos frequently, and I hope the old images will not be removed. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Drupal version?

Comment: Drupal version: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who really think that they want to hack core: Open includes/file.inc and look for the function drupal_unlink. Add return FALSE; as the first line and NO files will be deleted. Better yet, add a conditional statement that checks the $uri to ensure that it is a file that you don't want to delete.

I got above solution here,
[How to keep underlying file when deleting a Filefield value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2090/how-to-keep-underlying-file-when-deleting-a-filefield-value)

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, but basically there are two ways to go:

- Don't use an image field, but use an "entity relation" to a media entity instead. (Media is a core module >= Drupal 8.4, or a contrib module <= Drupal 8.3)
- User revisions: Create a new revision of your node every time you update the image field. You then can view older versions of the image in the version history of your page.

Comment: "Contrib" means it is a community contribution, published on Drupal.org - The module's name is [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media)

Comment: Thanks Hudri so much for your quick response:) I'll take a try

Comment: Dear Hudri, now I have the "Media" module. And I added a "File" field and select "Media Browser" widget. while editing this "File" field there are 2 buttons -- "remove" and "edit". I tried the "edit" function, I re-uploaded a new image, and the former uploaded image is removed. Is it possible not to remove the former one?

Comment: You should not edit, but remove and create a new media entity. I don't know about this module in D7, but in D8 there is an option to hide the edit button in the form display settings.

Comment: Thanks Hudri, actually I want to keep but not remove the old uploaded images. Is that possible?